# Why does the null character in insert mode insert the contents of the ". register?

Tags: insert-mode

When I enter insert mode and type `<C-SPACE>`, vim inserts the last inserted text, then exits insert mode. My guess is it's using the `".` register.

`<C-V><C-SPACE>` prints a null character. However when I enter the command `:imap`, it doesn't list any mappings. I was expecting there to be a mapping for the null character.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: `<C-Space>` just puts a space for me even with `<C-v>`. Does it do this when starting vim with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: I agree with @Tumbler41: I can't reproduce this behavior. Have you mapped `<space>` to your leader? See the output of `:imap <c-space>` to find out if it is mapped to something. See also [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press `<C-Space>` in insert mode, Vim understands `<C-@>` which is a built-in command that inserts the previously inserted text and leaves insert mode.

You can't see `<C-@>` in `:imap` because it is not a mapping.

But you could have pieced all that together from the doc:

```
:help i_ctrl-a
:help ".
```